# How to replace last 4 characters of a result from a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say i have a "SELECT * FROM TABLE" which result in a lot of rows with a lot of columns.

If i wan't to replace the last 4 characters in the third column, with X or *, how do i write that query?

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I cant do that because i'm working with personal data in the healthcare :(

Comment: Unless the DBMS is your patient you can tag it. And of course you can post mock data.

Comment: Well how can it be that i have to post all kinds of material, when the statement is rather clear: "How do I make a query that replaces the last 4 characters from a result with some other characters?" Why is it nesesary to post all kinds of material to work with, when all i have is what i've already wrote?

Comment: Is the content guaranteed to always 4 characters or more in length? so far solutions are making that assumption but it needs to be confirmed. Tagged SQL Server given the screenshot looks very much like SSMS and version number looks like SQL 2012 SP2

Comment: Maybe you should read up on dynamic data masking: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/01/25/use-dynamic-data-masking-to-obfuscate-your-sensitive-data/  or [MSFT docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2017)  or is this more than a display issue?

Answer (score 2):

In sql server, the following would work:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(100)= '123456789'

SELECT STUFF(@test, LEN(@test)-3, 4, 'XXXX')
```

Returns: `12345XXXX`

Comment: I've updated my post.. How whould you do if i wan't to replace the last four characters in the "SOCIALNUM column with X's ?

Comment: @MichaelEjvindTherkildsen, Just as I posted, replace `@test` with `SOCIALNUM`

Comment: @MichaelEjvindTherkildsen...What does that mean? Do you get an error? Wrong result?

Comment: And it was me that was blind

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
declare @value varchar(100) = 'Replace 4 characters '

select LEFT (@value, LEN(@value)-4) + REPLICATE('X',4)
```

Try this query

```
select LEFT (SOCIALNUM , LEN(SOCIALNUM )-4) + REPLICATE('X',4) ,* from CLIENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace last 4 characters with 'XXXX' if string is longer than 4

```
SELECT IIF(LEN(Column3) > 4, STUFF(Column3, LEN(Column3) - 3, 4, 'XXXX'), Column3)
```

or if you know the length is always 10

```
SELECT STUFF(Column3, LEN(Column3) - 3, 4, 'XXXX')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know im a bit late to the party, but i love to contribute so lets give it a shot with another angle, because we probably only need the birthdate from the ssn, right? (Assumptions made, shots fired)

```
SELECT LEFT(SOCIALNUM,6)+'****',* 
FROM CLIENT
WHERE CLIENTTYPE = '12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

SELECT Replace(Name,right(Ltrim(rtrim( Name )),4),'XXXX'), Name
  FROM  [dbo].[Employee]